# Display some of my web content in a Facebook Tab of my Facebook Aplication Page, posible?

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

i'd like to have a tab in my fb page with my last 5 posts, i would like to be able to insert an iframe, posible? if not, what options do we have for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it depends on which "canvas type" you're using for your FB app; An IFrame or FBML?

If it's an FBML then I'm not sure, you better consult FB's dev API.

If it's an IFrame this means that FB itself renders your app as an IFrame, which means you can use "real" HTML (in contrary to FBML which allows its own subset HTML and several FBML additional tags).
Then, in this IFrame app based, at its page which FB renders, you can add your own web content, as this is the very intention of the whole deal.

In other words, FBML or IFrame, they are both **designed to render your web content**, its just that each have its own restrictions.

Hope that helps somehow. You're welcome to tell us what exactly you're trying to render. If it's pure IFrame then I tell you - it's not a problem. Major apps on FB use IFrames as far as I can see.

Comment: well i haven't design the url yet cause i don't know if i'd be posible. i want to insert an url i will make with a different template that fits ok in the facebook page. btw, i'm using the Default facebook app style, wich one is it? thanks!